# Failed to resolve:

Tags: build-tools

```
android {     
dataBinding {     
    enabled true     
}
compileSdkVersion 26     
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'     
dexOptions {         
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"         
    preDexLibraries = false     
}     
defaultConfig {         
     applicationId "com.agentdesks.android.crm"         
     minSdkVersion 17         
     targetSdkVersion 26         
     versionName "3.3.2"         
     versionCode 145         
     multiDexEnabled true     
}
```

This is my build.gradle file and despite having downloaded the latest versions of sdk-build-tools I am getting this error
Error:(131, 17) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2
Any suggestion of fix?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that to use 26.+ I had to use the Android Studio 3.0+ for Oreo version. For now I have just downgraded the studio back to 2.3.3 and continue to use the 25.+ support version.

Thanks